# read NFC tags in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, rfid

I want to make a react-native app which can read the NFC tags. I am using **react-native-nfc** but cannot get it working. Can anyone help with figuring out what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Code in **index.android.js** is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';

import NFC, {NfcDataType, NdefRecordType} from "react-native-nfc";

export default class nfcTry extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.bindNfcListener();
  }

  bindNfcListener(){
    NFC.addListener((payload)=>{
      alert(payload.data.id);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Code in **AndroidManifest.xml** is the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nfctry"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: When you say "I am using react-native-nfc but cannot get it working", have you got any error message? What about the example of 'react-native-nfc', can you make it work?

Comment: @OlivierM The app gets installed on my tablet and works fine, I get no error, but when I try to read the NFC tag from the card nothing happens. I tried with the example given for ''react-native-nfc', it's the same thing.

Comment: Do you confirm NFC work on your tablet with a third-party application?

Comment: @OlivierM Yes, I did and it works. I have tried that with app called 'NFC TagInfo'.

Comment: Have you also created the file 'nfc_tech_filter.xml'? Have you check output of 'adb logcat'?

Comment: Yes, I have created  'nfc_tech_filter.xml'

Comment: @OlivierM also checked the logs, shows nothing.

Comment: Can you add the log to your initial question?

Comment: Is the tag/card you are using formatted with an NDEF message (also visible in TagInfo, on the second tab). Is anything happening (e.g. a sound played) when you approach the tablet with your tag/card ?

Comment: i am getting sounds of tag getting detected that is because of the device nfc but then after the app is opened with the following code is not giving any kind of indication i have put some toasts which are not getting displayed.

Comment: Try this
https://github.com/SMARTRACTECHNOLOGY/react-native-rfid-nfc You can use this for both IOS and android. Seems this will be useful to you.

Comment: @gingin, Are you able to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to make it to the goal!!
at this point of time your total code is missing with another npm package called [nfc-ndef-react-native](https://github.com/observ3r/nfc-ndef-react-native).

Link the following package with your existing code and you might face some issues with NDK , solve them too ! finally you would be able to make it!! I am running this app right now as needed.