# React native NFC reader

Tags: react-native, nfc

the same problem 
[react-native-nfc can't detect Mifare DESfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309152/react-native-nfc-cant-detect-mifare-desfire)
and from here
[read NFC tags in React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265736/read-nfc-tags-in-react-native-app)

Application build without any problem, started, but after this code, no any information, no any error, just nothing, another app from the store can detect NFC tag without the problem, but no react, can anyone help please?

```
NFC.addListener((payload)=>{
    alert(payload.data.id);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: need install both libraries and use first one

https://github.com/Novadart/react-native-nfc

https://github.com/observ3r/nfc-ndef-react-native